# Is it possible to get multiple outputs from one power query in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I have one big query in a file. I need to get multiple outputs from it with custom filters in multiple excel worksheets. Is it possible to do it WITHOUT loading the whole query table to each worksheets and then filtering it (it would make the file very big). I know that it can be done manually by duplicating the query and filtering it inside query settings but ideally i would like to filter each table in each worksheet by parameters chosen from dropdown list...

Comment: So duplicate the parameterized query but have it pick up parameter from indiv dropdown cells.

Comment: How can it be done via VBA?

Comment: OK i managed to do it by single output that is linked to query on separate sheet and then copy the content to relevant sheet

Answer (score 0):

No need for VBA I believe, if you have your filter in your workbook you can load them in Powerquery directly.
Either with a table loaded or with named range

Then keep you main query with the common part of all output and then reference it in other queries that you filter using your parameters loaded.

Loading a name cell in powerquery looks like:

```
Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="namedcell"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
```

You can do an IF using it as well:

```
Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows1", each [columntofilter] = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="source_url"]}[Content]{0}[Column1])
```

Comment: yes but i would have to manually change the "namedcell" for every worksheet that needs to have separate parameter

Comment: Maybe can you give more details on your structure